# Proof that the function $f$ is continuous, with domain euclidean space.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Let $B$ subset of $E^{n+1}$, with $E$ space euclidean.

Defined by $B=\{(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{n+1}): \alpha_1+...+\alpha_{n+1}=1  $ and $\alpha_i\geq0, \forall $ i$   \}$.

The function $f$ defined by

$f$: $E^{(n+1)}$$X$ $E^{n}$$X$...$X$ $E^{n}=E^{(n+1)^2}$ $\longmapsto E^{n}$

If $v\in E^{(n+1)^2}$ :

$v=(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{n+1},x_{1,1},...,x_{1,n},x_{2,1},...,x_{2,n},...,x_{n+1,1},...,x_{n+1,n})$.

And $f(v)= \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\alpha_i(x_{i,1},...,x_{i,n})$.

with $(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{n+1})$ in $B$.

Then prove that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: You are saying
$$f(v) = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\alpha_i(x_i^1,\ldots,x_i^n),$$
for $v$ of that form right? So what is $f(v)$ for $v \in E^{(n + 1)^2}$ that are not of that form?
Also I suggest using the notation $x_{i,j}$ to denote the different components, otherwise it looks like you raising the components to powers.

Comment: @EthanAlwaise  thanks, yes for $v$ form right.